# Permission denied / File too large

Tags: c

I recently started a C class in university and initially had this problem where after compiling the file (`gcc`) I got permission denied. I changed VSCode's terminal to bash (from windows) and somehow it fixed the problem.

Today, trying to study for exams, all the exe files from compiling gave permission denied errors. I've tried using `chmod +x` and I get "File too large" error even when its just a Hello World print statement. I've also tried putting it in different directories and same errors, even  `chmod` on the directories themselves.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm unsure what to do, it all worked properly a week ago. `ggc` creates the .exe file properly but after attempting to open it, it deletes itself. I realize this is an extremely simple question but I haven't been able to find any solution online for the past 3 hours.

The permissions on the c file (print hello world) are `-rw-r--r--` with size of `75`

The permissions on the .exe from the c file are `-rwxr-xr-x`  with size of `40766`

Parent directory is set to `drwxr-xr-x`

EDIT:

When running `gcc -v: Thread model: win32 and gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)` Using VSCode in Windows 10 with a bash terminal.

When compiling into `helloWorld.exe` and then `file helloWorld` I get `helloWorld: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows`

Comment: you run "./helloWorld" and instead of printing "Hello World" it deletes itself?

Comment: What OS?  What compiler version?  What exact commands are you typing to compile and run your program?  What's the full exact text of the error message?

Comment: It sounds like you're using a Linux-y compiler, and trying to run the resulting binary from either the Windows command shell (`cmd.exe`) or from the Ubuntu `bash` on Windows subsystem. Linux executables and Windows executables have completely different format (Linux uses [the ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), Windows [the PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)). I don't think I've ever seen a complaint about "file too large", but I assume trying to interpret one header type as the other could do weird things.

Comment: Must ask: do you have sufficient space in /tmp or /vat/tmp directories? Maybe these are placed on separated partition and this partition is simply full?

Comment: It's entirely possible I'm misinterpreting your precise circumstances; answering @NateEldredge's questions would be a first step in working out what's happening.

Comment: @yano Yes, if I run ```gcc -o helloWorld helloworld.c``` it generates an ```exe```. If I then ```./helloWorld``` I get:

```bash: ./helloWorld: Permission denied```. The exe then deletes itself after attempting this

Comment: @NateEldredge When running ```gcc -v```: ```Thread model: win32 and gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)```

Using VSCode in Windows 10 with a bash terminal. Commands used are in reply to yano below.

Comment: after compiling `ls -l helloWorld` shows `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions? What is the output of "file helloWorld"?

Comment: @ShadowRanger The only issue I have with this is that it used to work and for some reason, it doesn't anymore, so the commands or compatibility shouldn't be the issue. I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything since then..

Comment: I'm skeptical that the exe literally "deletes itself", since according to your message the executable never actually runs.  Do you mean that after running `./helloWorld` you can no longer see the file `helloWorld.exe` in a file listing (whereas you could see it beforehand)?

Comment: What happens if you try to run the program from an ordinary `cmd` prompt instead of `bash`, and likewise what happens when you list the directory with ordinary Windows `dir`?  Windows has a different scheme of file permissions than Unix does, and Unix commands like `ls` when run under Windows will show you some "translation" of the Windows permissions into Unix-style permissions, which may not always reflect what's really going on underneath.

Comment: @yano yes the permissions for ```helloWorld.exe``` are ```-rwxr-xr-x```. The the exe never runs because it gives ```Permission denied``` error.

Comment: with all this Windows/LInux mixing I don't exactly what tools your bash implementation supports, but "file <myFile>" is program that tells you what kind of file myFile is. It's not actually going to run it. I doubt this is the problem, but gcc could be compiling your executable for a different target or something ... just something else to 100% exclude as the problem.

Comment: Likewise, Unix-based utilities like `bash` will attempt to map Windows error codes onto Unix-style `errno` values, and again this sometimes results in error messages that don't really work (because the actual Windows error is something that doesn't correspond directly to any Unix concept).  So the key is to sort out whether the problem is with running the file at the level of the Windows OS, or if it is some problem with the particular way `bash` is trying to do it.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes exactly, the ```helloWorld.exe``` is present before executing, but after I try running it, and get the permission error, the file disappears from the file explorer. Will check using windows commands right now.

Comment: @yano Ah I see. When compiling into ```helloWorld.exe``` and then ```file helloWorld``` I get ```helloWorld: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows```

Comment: @NateEldredge Tried running it on the ```windows cmd``` inside VSCode and got ```Access is denied.```, Permissions are still the same.